# How to use react-native-i18n in detox[react-native]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, e2e-testing, detox

I want to test the alert message in detox,and the message use i18n.

```
const i18n = require("react-native-i18n");

describe("Example", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it("should show hello screen after tap", async () => {
    await element(by.id("btnLogin")).tap();
    I18n.t(LocaleKeys.errorMsg_invalidUsername);
    await expect(element(by.text(I18n.t(LocaleKeys.errorMsg_invalidUsername)))).toBeVisible();
    // await expect(element(by.text("Please input the email and password."))).toBeVisible();
  });

});
```

Run test and get the following error.

Test suite failed to run

```
/Users/leogeng/Desktop/studentREP/student-app/node_modules/react-native-i18n/index.js:14
export const getLanguages = () => RNI18n.getLanguages();
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:305:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (firstTest.spec.js:1:114)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Then I add the following code for jest:

```
{
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!(react-native(.*)?/|native-base(.*)?/|react-navigation/))"
  ]
}
```

and get error again:

```
 Validation Error:

  Module <rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js in the setupFiles option was not found.
```

Actually i confirm 'setup,js' exist in node_modules/react-native/jest.
I do not know why the error happens, anybody can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I resolve it by importing `i18n-js` instead of `react-native-i18n`.

Because `react-native-i18n` is not a plain javascript framework, `Detox` can't import it.

But `react-native-i18n` is using `i18n-js`, so you can access your translations without any problem

```
const I18n = require('i18n-js')

// and then you can use it for your tests
...
await element(by.text( I18n.t('hello') )).tap()
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's because you're using an old version of `node`, try to update and see if it solves the issue. Also, it's completely unrelated to `Jest` and you should probably revert your attempts to modify Jest settings if you don't have any issues with Jest unit tests; in anyway, it will not fix the detox issues.

In case you have some requirement or reason which forces you to keep `node` at a specific old version, you can bypass it by performing the test differently: have a demo screen only for the e2e tests (or even create a whole demo project just for e2e), in the demo screen you can have a button which performs what you need with `i18n` (changing locale or whatever), and in the `detox` test you tap this "demo" button before testing what you actually want.